# Numpy: creating indices for a sparse matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have a list of numpy arrays. Each array holds the value for the column I need there to be a 1 in a sparse binary matrix. The order in which the numpy array appears in the list is the value for the row for all the values in that respective numpy array. I am trying to use scipy.sparse.csr_matrix to do this. So I need two numpy arrays one for the column indices and the other for the row indices. Here is an example of what I need:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
b = np.array([10, 11, 12])
c = np.array([60, 100])
d = [a, b, c]

column = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 11, 12, 60, 100])
row = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`column` is just a flattened vector of d, so try:

`column = np.hstack(d)`

For `row`, this should work:

`row = np.hstack([np.ones(len(arr))*i for i, arr in enumerate(d)])`

Basically: step through d, make an array of ones of length of each item in d, multiply by its index in d, and then flatten all these into a vector.

Comment: `np.concatenate` does the same with these 1d arrays.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of other methods of generating the `row` array:

```
row = np.concatenate([np.ones_like(x)*i for i,x in enumerate(d)])

row = np.concatenate([[i]*len(x) for i,x in enumerate(d)])
```

for this small example the latter, with list replication, is quite a bit faster.  But with large arrays timings might go the other way.

For 1d arrays like this, `hstack` is the same as the default `concatenate`.

```
col = np.concatenate(d)
```

The full `sparse` call is then (for shape `(N,M)`)

```
sparse.csr_matrix((np.ones_like(col),(row, col)),shape=(N,M))
```

`coo`, `csr` and `csc` all accept this style of input.  `coo` is different in that it assigns the attributes exactly as given (so is fast).  The others do some sorting and summing (allowing for duplicate row,col pairs), and cleaning.